# Wordpress site running really slowly on WAMP

Tags: wordpress

My site runs really slowly on localhost on my WAMP server but runs fine on the live version online. The site and database are identical. What could be causing this issue? I'm also getting lots of "headers already sent" messages on the localhost version.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
}
```

Would you please above code in your current theme `functions.php`?